# redirect inputStream to JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I want to redirect the Standard System input to JTextField,
So that a user must type his/her input in JTextField (instead of console.)

I found `System.setIn(InputStream istream)` for redirecting `System.in`.

Here is my scratch code where i confused on reading from `JTextField - inputJTextField.`

```
 System.setIn(new InputStream() {
     @Override
         public int read() throws IOException {
         //how to read content?
         return Integer.parseInt(inputJTextField.getText());
      }
  });
```

My Question is **how to read content from GUI Component ( like JTextField and Cast it to String and other types after *redirecting the input stream***?

Comment: -1, Question is very convoluted. Just say what you mean!

Comment: What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am working on this. I will post the solution when i find.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert arbitrary string to InputStream, then use [ByteArrayInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

```
ByteArrayInputStream stringToInputStream ( final String s )
{
  // Assume your input is in UTF-8
  ByteArrayInputStream result =
    new ByteArrayInputStream( s.getBytes( "UTF-8" ) );

  return result;
}
```

However, I am not sure that your whole approach of setting your running process'es input stream will work.

Comment: What does this have to do with reading the content of a `JTextField`?

Comment: @Alexander How this could help me?

Comment: @little bunny foo foo.  With the way how OP re-edited question nothing.  With how it was posted originally, something.  It was not clear to me, whether OP has a problem with reading data from `JTextField` or converting string to `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

for multilines intput to the Gui would be better to look for [JEditorPane or JTextPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), lots of examples on this forum for `JEditorPanes` ot `JTextPanes` or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm)

Comment: `opArea.setText(opArea.getText()+"\n" + str);` please and why ???, or you have to look for How to use Html for Multilines output to the JLabel or JTextField

Comment: just by reads your ..., with new line ??? that's represents `"\n"`, I'm outta from this thread